# If $A_i$~$B_i,i=1,2,\cdots$ then $A = \cup_{i=1} ^\infty A_i$ and $B=\cup_{i=1} ^\infty B_i$ are also equivalent.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$A_i$~$B_i,i=1,2,\cdots$. Also $A_i \cap A_j=\emptyset,,B_i \cap B_j = \emptyset, i\neq j.$. Then $A = \cup_{i=1} ^\infty A_i$ and $B=\cup_{i=1} ^\infty B_i$ are also equivalent.

Proof is as follows.

Because $A_i$ ~ $B_i$ take

$\phi(x)=\phi_i(x)$ where $x \in A_i$ will be bijective mapping between $A$ and $B$.

Question I have is where disjointess of sets come into play? It is necessary condition but I can't think of examples where  if we cancel disjointess of sets then it's becomes false.

Comment: Try with $A_1=\{a\}, A_2=\{a\}, B_1=\{b\}, B_2=\{c\}$, and $A_1\cap A_2\ne\emptyset$. How would you construct $\phi$? Why does it not work? For an infinite family, if you insist, set $A_3=A_4=\ldots=B_3=B_4=\ldots=\emptyset$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop thanks

Answer (score 1):

Under disjointness, $x \in A$ implies there is a **unique** $i$ such that $x \in A_i$ and we can define $\phi (x)$ as $\phi_i(x)$. If $A_i$'s are not disjoint there could be more than one $i$ with $x \in A_i$ so $\phi (x)$ would not be well defined.

Comment: One would fix well-definedness with the Axiom of Choice, though the resulting map would not be a bijection.

Comment: Can you please bring examples of sets when it's not working?

Comment: For each $x$ you have assign just one value for $\phi (x)$. If $x \in A_i\cap A_j$ you need $\phi_i(x)=\phi_j(x)$ which may not be true since we don't have any control over the bijections $\phi_i$. @unit1991